# Ping Global IPv6 address on Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ipv6

My setup is like this:

Host: Windows 8 with Virtualbox
VM: Ubuntu 14.04 with 2 network adapters, eth0 a Host-only Adapter and eth1 a bridged adapter connected to my Wireless.

From my host to my VM I can ping the IPv4 address and the IPv6 link scope address of the eth1 interface. I can also ping the host from my VM .

In addition, I assigned a static IPv6 global scope address to the vm using "sudo ifconfig eth1 inet6 add aaaa::1".

I can't ping that address from my host. 
In other words, this works: "ping -6  fe80::a00:27ff:fe57:a9b9" (which is the link local scope address)
but this doesn't: "ping -6 aaaa::1"

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Edit:
Virtualbox has this to say: "On Linux hosts, functionality is limited when using wireless interfaces for bridged networking. Currently, VirtualBox supports only IPv4 over wireless. For other protocols such as IPv6 and IPX, you must choose a wired interface."

Atm my host has only a wireless connection and it is to this connection my eth1 bridged adapter is set. Is this perhaps the problem?

Comment: Does your ISP even support IPv6? Its pretty rare, and well, its worth considering as a preliminary troubleshooting step.

Comment: I assumed because I can use those link local ipv6 addressess that it does. But those are link-local of course.

Using http://test-ipv6.com/ it says my isp doesn't. Any advice on what step to undertake next?

Comment: I've not mucked about with ipv6 *without* ISP support or a tunnel. I don't think the ipv6 address you set may be *valid* and you're better off using something like a tunnel.

Comment: You can't normally bridge to a wireless client interface at all. The access point will refuse to talk to any other MAC address than the real client. VirtualBox does a bunch of nasty hackery to make it sort-of-work for IPv4. But IPv6 is a much cleaner protocol in which nasty hackery is discouraged or even impossible.